# AMD FX Series: 8 cores or 8 threads in 4 cores?

Tags: threads, cpu-cores

I've looked at FX-8XXX series processors on Windows, and they show as 4 core, dual-threaded processors. (4 cores w/ 2 threads per core)

The processors are advertised as 8-core. Do they actually have 8 cores, or just 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AMD FX-8000 series processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_FX_microprocessors#.22Vishera.22_.2832_nm_SOI.29) actually have 8 physical cores. Note that AMD cores and Intel cores are not directly comparable because [AMD cores share some resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer_%28microarchitecture%29#BULLDOZER_Core_.28aka_Module.29) (such as FPU and AVX units).

The thing that's most comparable to a core in an Intel CPU is likely the module in an AMD CPU, and there are only four of those. Just like an Intel physical core can contain two virtual cores, AMD physical modules contain two physical cores. But Windows has only one place to put a core count.

Comment: Because it has 4 modules, 8 cores, and 8 logical processors. Windows has no way to show modules, and AMD has to use that to make the Windows scheduler do the right thing. (Otherwise, it wouldn't be aware of the sharing of resources among cores on a module which is roughly analogous to the sharing of resources among physical cores on a virtual core.)

Answer (score 2):

In [Intel Hyper-Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), two threads share the same set of [execution units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_unit), and the architectural state of the processor (control and general-purpose registers) is duplicated so as to allow the processor core to more fully utilize parts of the execution unit when they are not in use, such as when the pipeline is stalled.

In [AMD FX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer_%28microarchitecture%29#Architecture), each module actually has two independent sets of integer execution units, allowing it to executing two processes (mostly) independently.  However, each module share a number of resources, including an instruction decoder, a (relatively large) [floating-point unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit), and L2 cache, so real-world performance is lower than two fully separate cores.

In effect, you have eight integer cores, but they behave more like four floating-point cores. As a result, Windows treats each module as a single core with two threads, just like an Intel processor with Hyper-Threading.

---

The aforementioned resource sharing, known as clustered multithreading (CMT), was a major reason for the low IPC of the *Bulldozer* architecture and its derivatives, especially in floating-point workloads. AMD's later *Zen* architecture abandons CMT and uses a larger, faster core with support for simultaneous multithreading similar to Intel Hyper-Threading. Each *Zen* core has separate execution resources. A more detailed, but non-exhaustive, comparison follows:

- In *Bulldozer* and derivatives, there are two separate integer units in each module. Each integer unit contains four execution units, two ALUs (which perform the actual integer computations) and two AGUs (which are used to calculate memory addresses for accessing memory). The two integer units effectively makes each module two integer "cores". On the other hand, *Zen* has fully separate cores, each with an integer unit consisting of *four* ALUs and two AGUs. (*Zen 2* adds a third AGU.) This alone substantially increases per-thread integer execution performance.
- In *Bulldozer*, each module has a single, shared floating-point unit, which can execute two 128-bit instructions at once. The two integer cores in each module share this single FPU. In *Zen*, each core has its own FPU, so multiple threads performing floating-point computations on *Zen* do not degrade performance the way it would on *Bulldozer*. Of course, various enhancements in the floating-point unit itself further improve performance. (*Zen 2* widens the FPU pipelines to enable faster execution of AVX2 instructions.)
- Important resources in the front-end of the processor cores are shared in *Bulldozer*. For example, each module has shared instruction fetch and a shared 4-wide instruction decoder. In comparison, each *Zen* core has separate front-end resources.

  - The instruction decoder is also shared in *Piledriver*, which was used in the last generation of desktop FX processors. *Steamroller* and *Excavator*, which were only used in A-Series processors, has separate decoders for each core. All of the *Bulldozer*-derived cores have shared instruction fetch.
  - In all generations of *Bulldozer*, branch predictors are shared between the two cores in each module.
  - Other enhancements in *Zen*, such as improved branch prediction (using perceptrons, a primitive form of machine learning AI) and the introduction of a micro-operation (μop) cache, further increase performance over the *Bulldozer*-based cores.

All told, AMD claimed a 52% overall increase in IPC over *Excavator*:

[image: AMD slide claiming Zen has 52% more IPC than Excavator]

If compared with *Piledriver*, the difference was as large as 64%.